# TSQL top 1 parameter assignment issue

Tags: t-sql, subquery, user-defined-functions, mode

I'm trying to get the MODE average for a set of zipcodes (zip code with most entries in a particular upload set). I want to make this a scalar function, instead of a stored procedure.

Why does this work:

```
Select Top 1 LocationZip
from UploadSetZipCodeCount
where WorkOrderSet = 31
Order by ZipCount desc
```

But not this:

```
Select @setbasezip= Top 1 LocationZip
from UploadSetZipCodeCount
where WorkOrderSet = 31
Order by ZipCount desc
```

My declaration type is correct for the LocationZip field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just a syntax issue... `select top 1` should come before the variable assignment:

```
Select Top 1 @setbasezip = LocationZip
from UploadSetZipCodeCount
where WorkOrderSet = 31
Order by ZipCount desc
```